# Include common configuration in several php5-fpm pools

Tags: php, web-server, php-fpm

Shortly: how can I include the same settings across several php-fpm pools without repeating them for each pool?

## Details

In php5-fpm there are **global** directives and **per pool** directives. In all examples and documentation, each pool has all required settings, e.g.

```
[www]
user = $pool
group = $pool
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
listen.owner = $pool
listen.group = $pool
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 5
pm.process_idle_timeout = 30s
chdir = /var/www/$pool

[www2]
user = $pool
group = $pool
listen = 127.0.0.1:9002
listen.owner = $pool
listen.group = $pool
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 5
pm.process_idle_timeout = 30s
chdir = /var/www/$pool
```

As you can see, most of the configuraton is the same, so I wonder if there is a way to put that configuration in a place where all pools can implicitly or explictly include them.

Just putting them at the bottom of the `[Global]` section is not working.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: You mean like in global section?

Comment: If I just add `pm` configuration at the end of the main "php-fpm.conf" file, it is not included. I get `the process manager is missing (static, dynamic or ondemand)`. I guess that's because that's a "per pool" type of setting.

Answer (score 10):

After trials and errors, I found that you can safely use the `include` directive to, well, **include** settings :-)

I created an additional `/etc/php5/fpm/common.conf` file:

```
user = $pool
group = $pool
listen.owner = $pool
listen.group = $pool
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 5
pm.process_idle_timeout = 30s
chdir = /var/www/$pool
```

And now all my pools can be as simple as this:

```
[www]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
include = /etc/php5/fpm/common.conf

[www2]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9002
include = /etc/php5/fpm/common.conf
```

Additional notes:

- yes, you have to specify the full path to the common file, because current path for fpm process is NOT the `pool.d` folder
- yes, all interpolation is done, so `$pool` becomes `www` or `www2` at runtime

Hope this could be also useful to someone else.

Comment: any idea why it doesn't work on php-fpm7.2? I get:  ERROR: [/etc/php-fpm-7.2.d/common.conf:1] unknown entry 'user'

Comment: @NizarBlond according to current documentation `user` is still a valid entry: http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php. So I guess something else must be wrong in your configuration file.

Comment: I was trying to override it inside pool config but included file seems not to get overriden. Any ideas?

Comment: @Baterka only a guess, but if you want to override something which is already defined in the common config, you should put the `include` directive at the top and THEN add the overrides. Honestly, I never tested that. Let us know how it works out for you so we can extend the answer accordingly.